# Why does making multiple assertions in a single Jest-Enzyme test case yields incorrect test result?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am currently testing a component which has a input field. These are my files:

`Input.js`

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input data-test="component-input" type="number" name="input-1" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} />
    ); 
  }
}
```

`Input-test.js`

```
describe('INPUT', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Input />);
  const input = wrapper.find({ 'data-test': 'component-input' });
  it('renders without errors', () => {
    expect(input.length).toEqual(1) &&
      expect(input.length).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

The test passes however, I expected the test to fail because the `it` block's callback function should return `true` only when both of the conditions are satisfied. In this case, Jest tests the first assertion which is `true` and does not seem to be testing the following assertion and gives a incorrect test result. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write multiple expectations you do just that:

```
expect(input.length).toEqual(1)
expect(input.length).toEqual(2)
```

You're trying to use the *return* value of `expect`, which is likely not what you believe it to be.